# Handling url in express.js+node.js? accepting specific words, double slash and more

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

**Homework:**
I know few things about url handling in node.js

```
app.param('id', /^\d+$/);
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});
```

Will only accept /user/1, /user/2 ...i.e. with id as integer only

```
app.get('/:type(discussion|page)/:id', ...)
```

will only accept type with value of discussion or page

```
app.param('range', /^(\d+)\-(\d+)?$/);
app.get('/range/range=:range', function(req, res){
var range = req.params.range;
    res.send('from ' + range[1] + ' to ' + range[2]);
});
```

will easily handle integer range and directly give us an array without any split or parsing and validation.

**Question :**

1. Normally server accept www.example.com/path and
   www.example.com//path in same way but in node.js I have to write two
   separate app.get check to do that. How can I achieve this by only
   one check so that /path, //path, ///path gives same response
2. I have one url which looks for /:path  and path can take values
   listed in a dictionary

   ```
   var dict={ 
       "a":"You called a", 
       "b": "b is second", 
       "c": "cats are all over internet"
   }
   app.get('/:charc',function(req,res){ 
      res.send(dict[charc]);
   });
   ```

   How can I restrict app to accept only a,b,c without putting an if else condition.
   currently I am doing

   ```
   if (typeof dict[charc] == 'undefined') res.send(404, 'Sorry, we cannot find that!');
   ```
3. Can I call range parameter(from homework part) sameway after '?' like

   ```
   app.get('/range?range=:range',...
   ```

   with url www.example.com/range?range=123-234

Comment: Set a path regex to accept multiple / `/+path`

Comment: Regarding #3, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to match query strings with express' router. Can't find a source that confirms this though.

Comment: Regarding #1 if there's no better solution something like `app.use(function (req,res,next) { req.url = req.url.replace(/[\/]+/g, '/'); next(); });` would make sure no subsequent routes would see any duplicate slashes.

Comment: ^ those who are declaring static dir...first declare this function else it would not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding #1 if there's no better solution something like

```
app.use(function (req,res,next) { 
    req.url = req.url.replace(/[\/]+/g, '/'); 
    next(); }
);
```

would make sure no subsequent routes would see any duplicate slashes. -@Andreas Hultgren

Regarding #3, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to match query strings with express' router. Can't find a source that confirms this though. -@Andreas Hultgren

Answer (score 0):

Followup to @Gaurav's comment for #1: Instead of changing the url in the route and continuing to handle the request, it *ought* to trigger a 3xx redirect so that the offending request is forwarded to the canonical variant. (This way the proper URL is updated in the browser. Or whatever type of client making the request is made aware that the original double-slash URL is technically invalid.)